# Epanechnikov kernel smoothing and Priestley-Chao (PC) kernel estimate

Tags: python, kernel

I wrote the Python code below to try to automate the application of kernel smoothing using the Epanechnikov kernel with a bandwidth of h = 0.4 calculating the Priestley-Chao kernel estimate of the function *f* at *x* = 0.5.

```
(Y_i, x_i)

x_vals = [0, 1/3, 2/3, 1]
y_vals = [2.1, 2.9, -8.3, 5.2]
```

Epanechnikov kernel:

$K(u) = {3\over4}(1-u^2)I(|u| \le 1)$

Priestley-Chao:

$f(x) = {b\ -\ a \over nh} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} K(x - x_i)/h)Y_i$

Below are my functions:

```
def epanechnikov_kernel(u):

    if abs(u) <= 1:
        return 3/4 * (1 - u**2)
    else:
        return 0

def pc_kernel_estimate(x, x_vals, y_vals, h):
    numerator = 0
    denominator = 0
    for i in range(len(x_vals)):
        u = (x - x_vals[i]) / h
        k = epanechnikov_kernel(u)
        numerator += k * y_vals[i]
        denominator += k
    f_hat = numerator / denominator
    return f_hat

n = 4
x = 0.5
h = 0.4
x_vals = [0, 1/3, 2/3, 1]
y_vals = [2.1, 2.9, -8.3, 5.2]

f_hat = pc_kernel_estimate(x, x_vals, y_vals, h)
```

I know the result I'm supposed to get is -2.09. However, my programming here produces -2.7. I thought maybe it was because at the 'f_hat = numerator / denominator' I didn't have the ((b-a)/nh) * (numerator/denominator) that that was my issue. When I make that change, it still does not produce the right answer. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your denominator is incorrect as you mentioned, here is the corrected code:

```
def epanechnikov_kernel(u):

    if abs(u) <= 1:
        return 3/4 * (1 - u**2)
    else:
        return 0

def pc_kernel_estimate(x, x_vals, y_vals, h, n):
    numerator = 0
    denominator = n*h
    for i in range(len(x_vals)):
        u = (x - x_vals[i]) / h
        k = epanechnikov_kernel(u)
        numerator += k * y_vals[i]
    f_hat = numerator / denominator
    return f_hat

n = 4
x = 0.5
h = 0.4
x_vals = [0, 1/3, 2/3, 1]
y_vals = [2.1, 2.9, -8.3, 5.2]

f_hat = pc_kernel_estimate(x, x_vals, y_vals, h, n)
f_hat
```

your original code would work for Nadaraya-Watson (NW) kernel estimate.